# How to get the current item being iterated in an each function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, this, each

I have a nested each function and want to know how I can refer to `this` single item when the if statement is triggered:

```
// check if array is empty
if(sameValArr.length === 0)
{
   $(this).hide(); // hide current video thumbnail item
}
else // not empty
{
   $(this).show(); // show current video tbumbnail item
}
```

Also tried:
`$(item).hide();`
`$(item[i]).hide();`

Currently, it's hiding all of the videos with class name `.video-thumbnail` at once and I only want to hide only the current one being iterated, not all.

**Full function:**

```
// check every time the user checks/unchecks inputs to show/hide the video
function checkboxChanged(videoTags)
{
    var checkedAttr = []; // array for checked attributes
    // change event listener for whenever one or more of the following checkboxes have been checked/unchecked
    $('#category-list :checkbox').change(function() 
    {
        checkedAttr = []; // refresh and initialize new array values
        $('#category-list :checkbox').each(function(i, item) // loop thru the input checkboxes
        {
            if($(item).is(':checked')) // item is checked
            {
                checkedAttr.push($(item).val()); // add it to array
            }
        });
        console.log("checkedAttr: ", checkedAttr);
        console.log("init videoTags: ", videoTags);


        // loop through each of the thumbnails to see if video tags match those in checkedAttr array
        $('.video-thumbnail').each(function(i, item)
        {
            console.log(i + " videoTags: ", videoTags);

            // TODO:
            // 1. compare the two arrays if there's any matching values in both
            // 2. if yes, store the matching value in a new array; otherwise do nothing
            // 3. check the new array if it isn't empty 
            // 4. if empty, hide the video; if not empty do nothing (show video)
            var sameValArr = []; // refresh array values
            console.log("INTERSECT: ", arrayIntersection(checkedAttr, videoTags));     // print resulting array intersection
            sameValArr = arrayIntersection(checkedAttr, videoTags); // store same matching array intersection values

            // check if array is empty
            if(sameValArr.length === 0)
            {
                $(this).hide(); // hide current video thumbnail item
            }
            else // not empty
            {
                $(this).show(); // show current video thumbnail item
            }
            console.log("<br/>");
        });
    });
}
```

**Update:**

I spent a few moments with the debugger and realized that the nested each function for video thumbnail class will be iterated up to nine times (the amount of video thumbnail classes present) along with checking each input if there's the same and since sameValArr is almost always empty, it hides the video one by one on each iteration. Still trying to fix it...

Comment: Did you checked what results `console.log(this)` ?

Comment: @dontvotemedown I didn't notice that! It does return only one video thumbnail. Must need further logic to target only one video and not all. Hmmm.

Comment: Yeah, your code seems fine. Did you tried adding a `debugger` at the beginning of the `each` ?

Comment: @dontvotemedown Yes, after digging in with the console, I added `return false` inside the if statement and it forced it out of the loop, but it hid the wrong video...the first video, so in a sense it's still going thru all, instead of the one specified in the each statement. Somehow, it's triggering the if statement on every video and I can never get it to show again.

Comment: Consider creating a jsfiddle.com of your issue... it will help yourself to get a good answer

Comment: @dontvotemedown Wow, it's really tough to crack down the problem. If anything, I think it has to do with the logic, the frequent nested looping is the cause and the code doesn't know which to go after, it just picks the first one it sees. About creating a jsfiddle, i don't think I can do that as I'm using the Youtube API with key.

Comment: If you think the problem are the nested loops, quit using jQuery's `each()`, use `for`. I never use `each()` myself.

Comment: @dontvotemedown `each` and `for` are the same functionality. I stepped through the debugger multiple times through every click and still can't understand why it would loop thru each of the individual videos and apply them all the same values or condition. Problem: Loops through each of the video thumbnail with the `sameValArr` results across all of them. If one video has a tag that matches checkbox input, all videos are being applied instead of the one with the tag only.

Answer (score 1):

Use the object passed in for you, `item`.

```
     $('.video-thumbnail').each(function(i, item)
        {
            console.log(i + " videoTags: ", videoTags);

            // TODO:
            // 1. compare the two arrays if there's any matching values in both
            // 2. if yes, store the matching value in a new array; otherwise do nothing
            // 3. check the new array if it isn't empty 
            // 4. if empty, hide the video; if not empty do nothing (show video)
            var sameValArr = []; // refresh array values
            console.log("INTERSECT: ", arrayIntersection(checkedAttr, videoTags));     // print resulting array intersection
            sameValArr = arrayIntersection(checkedAttr, videoTags); // store same matching array intersection values

            // check if array is empty
            if(sameValArr.length === 0)
            {
                $(item).hide(); // hide current video thumbnail item
            }
            else // not empty
            {
                $(item).show(); // show current video thumbnail item
            }
            console.log("<br/>");
        });
```

Comment: 'this' represents the same object as item.

Comment: I got it working using either `item` or `this`, as it turns out I added `return false` to act a break statement inside the if-else statement to force it out of the loop and it worked, but that spawned even more problems (such as hiding the first video thumbnail, not the intended one). SO in a sense, it's still trying to do all.